# jquery : element height returns 0

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

Hi have a dynamic content HTML that has the following structure

```
<Div id=1>
.....
</div>
and then 
<Div id=N>
.....
</div>
```

I am trying to print preview this in IE6 (yes IE6!)
Since IE6 DOES not support page-break-inside: avoid, I am using jquery

In the ready() function, I am checking for each div's height and then adding to the list of other divs' heights. If the sum is more than 700 (for instance), I insert a HR tag with page-break-after attribute.

So in this manner I can show the page breaks in IE6

However, the jquery for fetching the element height returns 0 under normal scenarios. That is, if there NO IE error thrown the element height is 0

If there is an IE error for instance Null reference or undefined, the jquery element height returns correct height.

Please help to resolve this

Jquery code used to add HR tag to show the page split

```
//Function to show the page break
function PageBreak()
{
    var i1=0;
    var prevId='';
    var heights='';
    var CurrentDiv=0;
    var CurrentDivHeight=0;

    //For each DIV which contains the medication, show the page break at appropriate rows
    $(".divtblPrint").each(function(i) 
    {
        //Check the current Height
        //if currentHeight + sum of previous heights is > HeightToCheck then 

        CurrentDivHeight=$(this).outerHeight(true);

        if((i1+CurrentDivHeight)>HeightToCheck)
        {
            var HTML='';
            HTML+="<hr class='pagebreak' style='visibility:hidden;'/>";
            $(this).before($('<div class="new">'+HTML+'</div>'));
            //reset the counters since this is fresh page
            i1=CurrentDivHeight;
            prevId='';
            //return;
        }
        else //height not yet crossed, so keep loops
        {
            prevId=$(this).attr('id');
            i1+=CurrentDivHeight;
        }

    });

}
```

pagebreak style:

```
<style>.pagebreak {page-break-after: always;}</style>
```

Comment: If div content is image, try $(window).load() instead of DOM ready

Comment: I tried load() but no use. thanks for recommendation though.

Comment: also add double quotes around div ID

Comment: and Also write add jquery code that may cause this problem

Comment: @ALi 
I am having this as the div tag template
<div class='divtblPrint' style='page-break-inside:avoid;' id='divtblPrintX'> where X is from 0 to N
will this cause a problem?

Comment: Please Edit your qauetsion including Jquery. do you get your elemnts like this?  $("#divtblPrint"+x)?

Comment: @Ali, I included the jquery code in my querstion. I use an iteration function to get the div ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted your comments and added my own comments. I think main problem was that your forgot to define HeightToCheck. Aslo you have many codes that are not in use. You can omit them. Please check the code snippet.

```js
function PageBreak()
{
    var i1=0;
    var prevId=''; //not in use?
    var heights=''; //not in use?
    var CurrentDiv=0; // not in use?
    var CurrentDivHeight=0; // Ok
    var HeightToCheck=200; //Did you forget this?

    $(".divtblPrint").each(function(i) 
    {

        CurrentDivHeight=$(this).outerHeight(true);

        if((i1+CurrentDivHeight)>HeightToCheck)
        {
            var HTML='';
            HTML+="<hr class='pagebreak' style='visibility:hidden;'/>";
            $(this).before($('<div class="new">'+HTML+'</div>'));
            i1=CurrentDivHeight; // Should this be i1=0 ?
            prevId=''; // not in use?

        }
        else
        {
            prevId=$(this).attr('id'); // not in use?
            i1+=CurrentDivHeight;
        }
        
        alert(i1);
    });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="divtblPrint">a</div>
<div class="divtblPrint">b</div>
<div class="divtblPrint">c</div>
<br>
<a onclick="PageBreak()">Click here to start loop</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Ali for the answer

Comment: Your'e Welcome. I don't know what you exactly wanted, however I think **i1=CurrentDivHeight;**  could be i1=0 (to reset to 0 after age break)?